# Newton's law of cooling ODE with time-varying environment temperature

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am attempting to solve the equation of Newton's law of cooling using an uncertainty in temperature $(22 \pm 3)\,^{\circ} \,\rm{C}$. I used a sinusoid to represent that but nevertheless got to a point where I could further do analytically.

$$\frac{dy}{dt} + ky = k \left (22+ 3 \sin \frac{\pi t}{12} \right), \quad y(0) = 37.5, \quad y(2) = 34$$

How would we solve this equation analytically? Please let me know.

Comment: I've edited your question, but in the future please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead of attaching an image.

Comment: Sorry for that and from next time I will use Mathjax.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "uncertainty on the temperature"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that you are solving a  first order linear ordinary differential equation and you can use an [integrating factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor) here.

Multiplying both sides of the equation by $e^{kt}$, we have

$$\frac{dy}{dt} e^{kt} + yke^{kt} = k \left (22+ 3 \sin \frac{\pi t}{12} \right)e^{kt}$$

Or, $$\frac{d}{dt}\left(ye^{kt} \right) = k \left (22+ 3 \sin \frac{\pi t}{12} \right)e^{kt}$$

Or, $$ye^{kt} = k \int \left (22+ 3 \sin \frac{\pi t}{12} \right)e^{kt} dt $$

Or, $$y = \frac{2 \left(216k^2 \sin \frac{\pi t}{12} + 11(144k^2 + \pi^2) - 18 \pi k \cos \frac{\pi t}{12} \right)}{144k^2 + \pi^2} + kc e^{-kt}$$

Now $$y(0) = kc + \frac{2(11(144k^2 + \pi^2) - 18 \pi k)}{144k^2 + \pi^2} = 37.5$$

$$y(2) = \frac{2 \left(216k^2 \sin \frac{\pi}{6} + 11(144k^2 + \pi^2) - 18 \pi k \cos \frac{\pi}{6} \right)}{144k^2 + \pi^2} + kc e^{-2k} = 34$$

We'll have to solve the above two equations for $k$ and $c$ using numerical techniques.

I got the following values:

$$k = 0.135985, c = 123.008$$

Finally, $$y(t) = 0.6374 \sin \frac{\pi t}{12} - 1.2272 \cos \frac{\pi t}{12} + 16.7272 \exp(-0.135985t) + 22$$

Comment: Well done ! For the numerical solution, you can extract $c$ from $y(0)$ and plug it in $y(2)$. There is an analytical solution for $k$ in terms of the generalized Lambert function. Nice to know it but of no practical interest. Just to make it fancy ! Cheers and (+1).  :-)

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot @PTDS  for your answer. Do you mind please explain how you found the 4th equation?

Comment: Are you asking about the following step:
$$y = \frac{2 \left(216k^2 \sin \frac{\pi t}{12} + 11(144k^2 + \pi^2) - 18 \pi k \cos \frac{\pi t}{12} \right)}{144k^2 + \pi^2} + kc e^{-kt}$$
i.e., the step where I get the value of $y$ after integrating the RHS and dividing it by $e^{kt}$?

Comment: @PTDS, Yes that’s the point I don’t understand

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Claude Leibovici